# Android stop user from closing the app

Tags: java, android, performance, android-intent, mdm

Is there a way we can build a custom MDM, to force the app to be always open. i.e don't let the user close.

I am building a image gallery app to be on display for users. but I dont want them to be able to close my app.

Thanks

some thing like this ?

```
public class IntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String TAG = IntentReceiver.class.getSimpleName();


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onReceive - intent => " + intent.getAction());

        //Get Intent
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if("android.intent.category.HOME".equals(action)) {

            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClass(context, MainActivity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
```

But then, I also need to know when the app is closed or killed ?

> Let me try to explain better. imagine if an artist wants to display his work via 10 android device. all in the Wall. So he can use this app. I want to lock-down the device. to only run this app and nothing else to work. 
>   Similar conset when you go to a phone shop and all the device is running a demo app and you can't quit it with out a password. (i.e Apple Store) you can't quit the app running on these Ipads

Comment: This sounds unpleasant

Comment: why would any user want this?

Comment: Well, want to build a image slide show. to be display at my desk. I dont want no one from closing the app. only via password

Comment: This App will only be used by a client

Comment: @Joolah you could develop a custom launcher, which by definition can't be exited

Comment: I will uninstall  the app the moment it will do something like  this..

Comment: nobalG its not open to the public app. its for artist and shop owners

Comment: @ neomega Could you please explain a bit more on that ?

Comment: @Joolah By developping a launcher, you are the home and because of this, the back and home button will return to you. Then you just have to don't display any app on it and do your gallery. 
Then you just have to put the settings hidden somewhere with a password check

Comment: @neomega I tried something like that. but when I press the home button, It brinds app 3 lancher options. even if i choose my app. next time I press home bt the 3 option comes back

Comment: @neomega u tried this sample : http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-launcher-on-android--cms-21358

Comment: Maybe you can create homescreen widget for that? Android users will be furious if you try preventing them from leaving the app (at least I will)

Answer (score 1):

I've written a post specifically on Kiosk mode on Android - past just 'task pinning'.

http://www.sureshjoshi.com/mobile/android-kiosk-mode-without-root/

- Create a DeviceAdminReceiver and put it in your manifest
- Then, run dpm to give yourself device admin access

adb shell dpm set-device-owner com.sureshjoshi.android.kioskexample/.AdminReceiver

- Verify you're the device owner in the app, and you're off to the races

There is a fair amount of work to it, however, once you do the boilerplate, you'll end up using this snippet to enable and disable.

```
private void enableKioskMode(boolean enabled) {
    try {
        if (enabled) {
            if (mDpm.isLockTaskPermitted(this.getPackageName())) {
                startLockTask();
                mIsKioskEnabled = true;
                mButton.setText(getString(R.string.exit_kiosk_mode));
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.kiosk_not_permitted), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            stopLockTask();
            mIsKioskEnabled = false;
            mButton.setText(getString(R.string.enter_kiosk_mode));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: Log and handle appropriately
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @SJoshi, I can't access the link url. say, website down

Comment: @Joolah Are you sure? I haven't had any downtime on that site in a few weeks.

Comment: ur website was ok. just that blog post was down for about 1 hour this morning

Comment: @Joolah Ah, okay, sorry about that!

Comment: I done that it works now. But I need to update the app, I can't re run the project via Android Studio it says, DELETE_FAILED_DEVICE_POLICY_MANAGER

ALso I can't delete the app from the device. pls advice. thanks you

Answer (score 0):

For these scenarios, do not reinvent the wheel, instead install Android 5.0 or newer and use its ["kiosk mode" a.k.a. "task pinning"](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/85013)

Answer (score 0):

As said by @Sarge from 5.0 there's the Kiosk mode available. If you're not running on 5.0 please let me know and 'ill take some times to search onto my old project and give you a pré lollipop Home-made Kiosk mode (no need to flash the tablet or anything, just programming)

Comment: thank you for your time. I intent to use on Samsung GT tablet. they are running on 4.4.2. they wont be running 5.0.

Comment: There are also many other reasons why it's better to use Android 5+. I suggest trying harder to get there a device with Android 5 support…

Comment: Joolah I'll try to give it a look this afternoon, be aware that it'll need lots of things to do like putting your app as the "Home Screen", will do it ASAP

@SargeBorsch I agree getting the 5+ version will be easier but the problem is that some manufacturers doesn't allow users to get the next version, so you have to compose with what you have (still >200€ per device so buying new ones to have right version isn't always the best way.) MoreOver, doing it the 5+ way means you can't open your app to (let's say it's a professionnal app) every company/users it should reach, need to keep it in mind

Comment: @Bxtr SargeBorsch, Thanks guys, I appropriate your help. The SAMSUNG GALAXY TAB 3 10.1 P5210  Will not be able to be upgraded to 5.0. Also, I can not root these devices.

Comment: they won't need to be root ;)

Comment: I mean, replacing the device with a "better" one is also a thing to consider